# PySpark: Using Window Functions to roll-up dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, window-functions

I have a dataframe `my_df` that contains 4 columns:

```
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
|         user_id|         domain|isp_flag|frequency|
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
|            josh|     wanadoo.fr|       1|       15|
|            josh|      random.it|       0|       12|
|        samantha|     wanadoo.fr|       1|       16|
|             bob|    eidsiva.net|       1|        5|
|             bob|      media.net|       0|        1|
|           dylan|    vodafone.it|       1|      448|
|           dylan|   somesite.net|       0|       20|
|           dylan|   yolosite.net|       0|       49|
|           dylan|      random.it|       0|        3|
|             don|    vodafone.it|       1|       39|
|             don|   popsugar.com|       0|       10|
|             don|      fabio.com|       1|       49|
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
```

This is what I'm planning to do-

> Find all the `user_id` where the maximum frequency `domain` with `isp_flag=0` has a frequency that is less than 25% of the maximum frequency `domain` with `isp_flag=1`.

So, in the example that I have above, my `output_df` would look like-

```
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
|         user_id|         domain|isp_flag|frequency|
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
|             bob|    eidsiva.net|       1|        5|
|             bob|      media.net|       0|        1|
|           dylan|    vodafone.it|       1|      448|
|           dylan|   yolosite.net|       0|       49|
|             don|      fabio.com|       1|       49|
|             don|   popsugar.com|       0|       10|
+----------------+---------------+--------+---------+
```

I believe I need window functions to do this, and so I tried the following to first find the maximum frequency domains for `isp_flag=0` and `isp_flag=1` respectively, for each of the `user_id`-

```
>>> win_1 = Window().partitionBy("user_id", "domain", "isp_flag").orderBy((col("frequency").desc()))
>>> final_df = my_df.select("*", rank().over(win_1).alias("rank")).filter(col("rank")==1)
>>> final_df.show(5)   # this just gives me the original dataframe back
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get to the final `output_df` I printed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the following: calculate the max_frequencies (max_0, max_1) for each user having isp_flag == 0 or 1 respectively. and then filter by condition `max_0 < 0.25*max_1` and plus `frequency in (max_1, max_0)` to select only the records with maximum frequency.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

# set up the Window to calculate max_0 and max_1 for each user
# having isp_flag = 0 and 1 respectively
w1 = Window.partitionBy('user_id').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn('max_1', F.max(F.expr("IF(isp_flag==1, frequency, NULL)")).over(w1))\ 
  .withColumn('max_0', F.max(F.expr("IF(isp_flag==0, frequency, NULL)")).over(w1))\ 
  .where('max_0 < 0.25*max_1 AND frequency in (max_1, max_0)') \ 
  .show() 
+-------+------------+--------+---------+-----+-----+                           
|user_id|      domain|isp_flag|frequency|max_1|max_0|
+-------+------------+--------+---------+-----+-----+
|    don|popsugar.com|       0|       10|   49|   10|
|    don|   fabio.com|       1|       49|   49|   10|
|  dylan| vodafone.it|       1|      448|  448|   49|
|  dylan|yolosite.net|       0|       49|  448|   49|
|    bob| eidsiva.net|       1|        5|    5|    1|
|    bob|   media.net|       0|        1|    5|    1|
+-------+------------+--------+---------+-----+-----+
```

**Some Explanations per request:**

- the WindowSpec `w1` is set to examine all records for the same **user**(partitionBy), so that the F.max() function will compare all rows based on the same user.
- we use `IF(isp_flag==1, frequency, NULL)` to find frequency for rows having isp_flag==1, it returns NULL when isp_flag is not `1` and thus is skipped in F.max() function. this is an SQL expression and thus we need `F.expr()` function to run it.
- `F.max(...).over(w1)` will take the max value of the result from executing the above SQL expression. this calculation is based on the Window `w1`.

Comment: this worked great, thanks! could you explain the window function though? also, what does `F.max(F.expr("IF(isp_flag==1, frequency, NULL)"))` do here? and why is there a `NULL` in there?

Comment: @kev, added some explanations in the post.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Also, why did we need `AND frequency in (max_1, max_0)` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Hi, @kev, I saw you have `rank()==1` in your filter, and `frequency in (max_1, max_0)` is basically to filter by the max values of frequency which does the same as  `rank() == 1`. Just a reminder, you will get more than 2 rows per user if there are ties with max_1 or max_0.

Comment: BTW. you can remove `.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)` from w1 since it's default (unbounded) when there is no orderBy() clause in the WindowSpec.